# checking if two images views are intersecting when moving

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

i am developing an app where one imageview is moving in circular direction and checking if it is intersecting with any other view

this is an image view which is moving

```
circleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo16.png"]];
circleView.frame = CGRectMake(30 , 30, 30, 30);
```

this is another view with which i want to check if it is intersecting

```
detectrect=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo16.png"]];
detectrect.frame=CGRectMake(160, 160, 80, 80);



[self.view addSubview:detectrect];


[self.view addSubview:circleView];
```

now i have an method where i check using timer if they intersect each other

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(imageviewcoordinates) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)imageviewcoordinates;
```

{

```
if (CGRectContainsRect([self.detectrect frame ],[self.circleView frame ]))
{
    NSLog(@" intersection ");
}
```

}

nut i am unable to detect it 
don't know whats going wrong  here

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is output some NSLog to the debug area (from your imageviewcoordinates method):

```
NSLog(@" self.detectrect.frame.origin.x : %f ", self.detectrect.frame.origin.x);
NSLog(@" self.detectrect.frame.origin.y : %f ", self.detectrect.frame.origin.y);

NSLog(@" self.detectrect.frame.size.width : %f ", self.detectrect.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@" self.detectrect.frame.size.height : %f ", self.detectrect.frame.size.height);

NSLog(@" self.circleView.frame.origin.x : %f ", self.circleView.frame.origin.x);
NSLog(@" self.circleView.frame.origin.y : %f ", self.circleView.frame.origin.y);

NSLog(@" self.circleView.frame.size.width : %f ", self.circleView.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@" self.circleView.frame.size.height : %f ", self.circleView.frame.size.height);
```

To ensure you are getting some values you can compare and so you can see why the CGRectContainsRect is failing.

Comment: Hi Ade ,yup i checked it i am doing  NSLog(@" x=%f ",circleView.frame.origin.x); bt i am getting same value each time as i am moving ? its 30 what would be the problem bt i can see that image view is moving ? why this strange behavior?

Comment: Try setting the frame after you add the subviews. You should create the uiview, add it to view hierarchy(subview in your case), set initial position/frame and then animate.

Comment: hey ade i tried that bt not working following is the whole code with animation for circular movement of image view

Comment: CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;pathAnimation.duration = 3.0;pathAnimation.repeatCount = 10;CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();450);CGPathAddArc(curvedPath, NULL, 160,260, 160/2,0,45*M_PI*2, YES); pathAnimation.path = curvedPath;CGPathRelease(curvedPath);

Comment: Your UIView is not moving. You are animating your UIView's core animation layer not the view itself. You need to either animate the view instead of the layer or detect the intersection of the layers.

Comment: Hi Ade ya u are right UIView is not moving so i tried pronging layer position NSLog(@" Circle VIew Layer frame %f, %f, %f, %f",circleView.layer.frame.origin.x,circleView.layer.frame.origin.y,circleView.layer.frame.size.width,circleView.layer.frame.size.height);bt it shows the same coordinates as i added it ? is there any other way i can move image view in circular path ? or how can i detect layers intersection

Answer (score 0):

if(CGRectIntersectsRect(photo.frame, photo2.frame))
use this one to check intersection!